# iterated loop spaces and configuration spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, operads, loop-spaces, monads, configuration-spaces

In the lecture notes by J.P. May, The geometry of iterated loop spaces, Chapter 5, formula (1), (2) and (10), a map 
$$
\phi: Hom_T(X,\Omega Y)\to Hom_T(SX,Y)
$$
is defined. And a map
$$
\eta_n=\phi^{-n}(1_{S^nX}):X\to \Omega^n S^nX.
$$

Question: I do not quite understand what does $\eta_n$ mean? What means $\phi^{-n}(1_{S^nX})$?

What means $\phi^{-n}$?

Comment: Is it not the unit of the adjunction between iterates of Omega and Sigms?

Comment: [Asked (and answered) on math.SE too.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303535/iterated-loop-spaces-and-configuration-spaces) Please, stop doing that. This is at least the second time that I answer one of your questions on math.SE only to discover you had asked it at the same time on MO, and had already gotten an answer...

Comment: Sorry Prof. I will delete it.

Comment: Haha, I'm not a prof, far from it :) don't delete it if you don't want to (Peter Michor's answer is good), simply stick to one site and wait for a bit before asking on the other in the future.

Comment: Dear Prof.Najib Idrissi, I found it cannot be deleted. I am quite sorry for this.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your instructions. I will remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Phi^n:Hom(X,\Omega^nS^nX)\to Hom(SX,\Omega^{n-1}S^nX)\to \dots\to Hom(S^{n-1}X,\Omega S^nX) \to Hom(S^nX,S^nX)$.